# Matplotlib trendline code.. will run but won't plot the p(x) line.... I don't know whats wrong.

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

Please help with this... I can't get the line to plot. it will plot the x,y scatter, but no trendline will appear.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as fs
name = ["SlowFast","Bedrock","MeanSlow","hAgDenkm","hSinDenkm","hAgSl","hAgFa","hSinSl","hSinF","LogSlowFast","LogBedrock","LogMeanSlow","LoghAgDenkm",#
             "LoghSinDenkm","LoghAgSl","LoghAgFa","LoghSinSl","LoghSinFa"]
data = np.genfromtxt('C:\Users\Ben\Documents\R\LWM_Study\LWM52714BigRun.csv',dtype = 'float' , delimiter = ',' , skip_header = 0, skip_footer= 20 , names = name) ### data array###

x=data["LogSlowFast"]
y=data["LoghSinDenkm"]
z = np.polyfit(x,y,1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
fs.plot(x,y,'ro',x,p(x),'r--')
fs.ylabel("a")
fs.xlabel("LogSlowFast")
fs.show()

print x,y,z,p
```

Comment: can you show us the output from the print statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be something wrong with your data `x` and `y`. If you replace the first part of your code with some artificial data:

```
x=np.linspace(0,1,100)
y=x**2
z = np.polyfit(x,y,1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
fs.plot(x,y,'ro',x,p(x),'r--')
fs.ylabel("a")
fs.xlabel("LogSlowFast")
fs.show()
```

you will get:

[image]

So, apart from the data everything is kept as in your code.

Interesting things about the data:

- `x.dtype`
- `y.dtype`
- are there possibly any NaNs in the data?
- `p`

My guess is that you have a `nan` or possibly an `inf`in the data. That'll make the trendline become `nan` as well and thus invisible.

Maybe the first point to verify is that the contents of `p` are something reasonable.

Comment: Thanks for helping... I still had headers in the CSV and fixed the problem by Filling the SKip header== 20... now I just gotta figure out how to get the zeos out of my data